# How can I tell goimports to prefer one package over another?

Tags: go

This file:

```
package foo

func errorer() error {
    return errors.New("Whoops")
}
```

Will be transformed to this with `goimports`:

```
package foo

import "errors"

func errorer() error {
    return errors.New("Whoops")
}
```

However, I'd like to use the `github.com/pkg/errors` package everywhere in this project, and not the `errors` package.

Can I tell `goimports` to always prefer the `github.com/pkg/errors` package?

Comment: I don't think you can. Just import github.com/pkg/errors "manually".

Comment: Welcome to the world of `goimports` and its wrong package imports.  Wait until you get to `templates`!  In reality, get away from this automated imports management and just learn the packages yourself - you'll thank us later.  Besides, to have proper intellisense in any IDE (VIM, Atom, Sublime, VS Code, VS, IntelliJ - ive used all!), *you will need to specify the Import first anyways!*

Answer (score 4):

Using [`.goimportsignore`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports) would not work in your case as the package you want to ignore is in the standard lib and not under GOPATH.

The `-local` flag would also not work because both the packages have the same name so `errors` will still be chosen over `pkg/errors`.

Your options are to write your own version of `goimports` using the [`golang.org/x/tools/imports`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/imports)

Or another inconvenient way is to make sure you call `error.Wrap` or one of the other functions the first time in a new file, rather than `errors.New` so that `goimports` can identify `pkg/errors`.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this but according to the docs at:
https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/cmd/goimports/doc.go

> To exclude directories in your $GOPATH from being scanned for Go
>   files, goimports respects a configuration file at
>   $GOPATH/src/.goimportsignore which may contain blank lines, comment
>   lines (beginning with '#'), or lines naming a directory relative to
>   the configuration file to ignore when scanning. No globbing or regex
>   patterns are allowed. Use the "-v" verbose flag to verify it's working
>   and see what goimports is doing.

So you could try excluding the errors directory.

Comment: Those are for packages under GOPATH, `lines naming a directory **relative** to the configuration`